# Conditional Incremental in sorted data in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis, m

**My dataset**

The dataset is in Excel. I have a column with unique IDs, some data that is out of scope of this question, and an "if" condition which returns true or false based those data. The first true/false is Null because it evaluates the data from the previous row to determine the boolean.

```
ID     boolean
15032  null
25638  false
45035  false
55139  true
15235  true
14550  false
15035  false
13035  false
12235  true
```

**Desired Output**

Add a column called ConditionalIncremental. Starting at 1, incrementing only when the row's boolean is equal to TRUE, otherwise it stays the same as the previous row.

```
ID     boolean   ConditionalIncremental
15032  null      1
25638  false     1
45035  false     1
55139  true      2
15235  true      3
14550  false     3
15035  false     3
13035  false     3
12235  true      4
```

Basically; if boolean = true then previous row + 1 else previous row.

**What I've found**

- All references I find are about assigning indexes based on the group ID common to each record. My issue is that I want to CREATE the group ID (it is the incremental conditional index). such as this https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/numbering-grouped-data-power-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the boolean column is set to type logical

Add column .. index column ...

Add column ... custom column ...

```
= 1+List.Sum(List.Transform(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[boolean],1+[Index]), each if _=true then 1 else 0))
```

sample:

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"boolean", type logical}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Incremental", each 1+List.Sum(List.Transform(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[boolean],1+[Index]), each if _=true then 1 else 0))),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"boolean", type logical}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each 
let a = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index",(x)=> x[Index] <= [Index]),
b = a[boolean],
c =  List.RemoveItems(b, {false, null})
in  List.Count(c)+1

)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

And he's another method that doesn't require adding an Index column:
*You don't write what you want for the first row. I just assumed a `1`. But if the contents of the boolean column make a difference for the **first** row, you can easily modify that*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"boolean", type logical}}),
    #"Add Conditional Incremental" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") &
            {List.Generate(
                ()=>[ci=1, idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(#"Changed Type"),
                each [ci = if #"Changed Type"{[idx] + 1}[boolean] = true then [ci] +1 else [ci], idx=[idx]+1],
                each [ci]
            )}, Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type") & {"Conditional Incremental"}
    )
in
    #"Add Conditional Incremental"
```

[image]